# Breaking parent loop in tcl

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, tcl

I have a for loop in a while loop. I have a condition to break the while in the for loop.

Here is the code :

```
while {[gets $thefile line] >= 0} {
   for {set i 1} {$i<$count_table} {incr i} {
   if { [regexp "pattern_$i" $line] } {
      for {set break_lines 1} {$break_lines<$nb_lines} {incr break_lines} {
         if {[gets $thefile line_$break_lines] < 0} break
      }
   }
   #some other process to do
}
```

I want to skip `$nb_lines` in the file parsed to do other thing further. Here the break, breaks the for loop, so it doesn't work.

Can the for loop make the while loop broken  ?
 But the break is just for 1 (or more) lines, i want to continue to parse the file after the break to process line further

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `break` command (and `continue` too) doesn't do multi-level loop exit. IMO, the *simplest workaround* is to just **refactor** the code so you can `return` to exit the outer loop. However, if you can't do that, then you can use something like this instead (for 8.5 and later):

```
proc magictrap {code body} {
    if {$code <= 4} {error "bad magic code"}; # Lower values reserved for Tcl
    if {[catch {uplevel 1 $body} msg opt] == $code} return
    return -options $opt $msg
}
proc magicthrow code {return -code $code "doesn't matter what this is"}

while {[gets $thefile line] >= 0} {
   magictrap 5 {
      for {set i 1} {$i<$count_table} {incr i} {
         if { [regexp "pattern_$i" $line] } {
            for {set break_lines 1} {$break_lines<$nb_lines} {incr break_lines} {
               if {[gets $thefile line_$break_lines] < 0} {magicthrow 5}
            }
         }
      }
   }
   #some other process to do
}
```

The `5` isn't very special (it's just a custom result code; Tcl reserves 0–4, but leaves the others alone) but you need to pick a value for yourself so that it doesn't overlap with any other uses in your program. (It is mostly possible to redo the code so it works with 8.4 and before too, but it's quite a bit more complex to rethrow an exception there.)

Be aware that custom exception codes are a “deep magic” part of Tcl. *Please use ordinary refactoring instead if you can.*

Comment: In case you're wondering, 0 is for normal success, 1 is for an error (and causes a stack trace to be built during the unwinding), 2 is for `return`ing from the current procedure, 3 is for `break` and 4 is for `continue`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps obvious, but you can use an additional variable (`go_on`) to break the while:

```
while {[gets $thefile line] >= 0} {
  set go_on 1
  for {set i 1} {$i<$count_table && $go_on} {incr i} {
    if { [regexp "pattern_$i" $line] } {
      for {set break_lines 1} {$break_lines<$nb_lines && $go_on} {incr break_lines} {
        if {[gets $thefile line_$break_lines] < 0} { set go_on 0 }
      }
     }
   }
   #some other process to do
}
```

Comment: Hi, ok this works to beak the while. But it is a too hard break, i can't continue to parse the file and i can't do the other processing at the # point.Do you have an idea to continue the parsing ? (i have edited a little bit my question)

Comment: I not very clear on what you want to do, however this might work

Comment: We are near the end but it's not good. It is my fault, i am not enough clear. I want to parse a file with the while, during the parsing, I am searching for pattern that is non-regular (that's why i do the for loops). When i found pattern i want to skip lines to process line further. I want to break the while just for 1 (or more) line but not to stop parsing